# How Do i Iterate through a JSON object in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On my ReactJS file, I JSON.stringify my object to see what i get.

```
return ( 
    <div> 
        { JSON.stringify(peopleChannel) };
    </div>
)
```

I get return something like this

```
{
  "Y3WJb6": {
    "photoURL": "https://myimage.com",
    "email": "abc.com"
  },
  "Yzfd6": {
    "photoURL": "https://myimage23.com",
    "email": "adfasfd.com"
  }
}
```

How do I render it into like a list?

Comment: 1) Don't stringify it. You can't iterate over a string (you can, but not how you want). 2) You need to `map` over the `Object.values` and extract the data you need and return a new array.

Comment: You can `JSON.parse` it and iterate through as an object.

Comment: @sidc I think it might already be an object

Comment: @evolutionxbox. Oh I thought he was getting JSON from an API or file, in which case you need to parse it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object. You either mean JSON (which is a string) or a JS object.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes indeed it is a Object!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map over Object.values(peopleChannel), or if you need the object keys as well use Object.entries:

```
   return (
    <div>
    {Object.entries(peopleChannel).map(([id, {photoURL, email}]) => (
      <div>
        <div>{id}</div>
        <div>{photoURL}</div>
        <div>{email}</div>
      </div>
    ))}
    </div>
   )
```

Comment: Thank you! I stop trying map when its a Object instead of Array. I feel so dumb now. Thank you so much.